# lists:usort for nth element in tuple

Tags: erlang, sorting

I need to sort tuples according to the second element of each tuple but apparently usort/1 only works with the first element. So I have to swap the elements, usort them and swap back.Is there an easier way?Also is there a way to sort in descending order (I know sorting and reversing can be done, but just want to know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [keysort/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keysort-2) function (or its counterpart [ukeysort/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#ukeysort-2))?

```
> lists:reverse(lists:keysort(2, [{a,2}, {b,1}, {c, 3}])).
[{c,3},{a,2},{b,1}]
```

If you don't sort very big lists this is probably the most readable solution you can get.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a better answer:

There's a second version of sort that takes a sorting function:

```
lists:sort(Fun, List1) -> List2
```

Here's an example that sorts on the second element in a tuple:

```
lists:sort(fun(A, B) ->
                   {A1, A2} = A,
                   {B1, B2} = B,
                   if
                       A2 > B2 ->
                           false;
                       true ->
                           true
                   end
           end, YourList).
```

Answer (score 2):

An improved version of bmdhacks' solution:

```
lists:sort(fun(A, B) ->
                   {_, A2} = A,
                   {_, B2} = B,
                   A2 =< B2
           end, YourList).
```

Underscores are better then A1 and B1, because the compiler will give warnings
for those.

To sort in descending order, just change <= to >=.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too hard to write your own sort function (adapted from a common example):

```
qsort([]) -> [];
qsort([Pivot|Tail]) ->
    {PivotFirst, PivotSecond} = Pivot,
    qsort([{FirstElement, SecondElement} || {FirstElement,SecondElement} <- Tail, SecondElement < PivotSecond])
        ++ [Pivot] ++
        qsort([{FirstElement, SecondElement} || {FirstElement,SecondElement} <- Tail, SecondElement >= PivotSecond]).
```